# Quartz triggers are in the past

Tags: java, timer, quartz-scheduler

I have 750 Quartz Jobs with 1 trigger each.

Dumping the trigger data show a next fire time with a time in the past.
The dump is from 15:55 Berlin/Europe timezone.

Is the nextfire time wrong or is Quartz overloaded with too many jobs?

Quartz Jobs

```
Name= INSTANT_KPI_DEF_ID_1000708 Group=DEFAULT NextFireTime=Thu Feb 09 15:15:30 CET 2017 Priority=5 Paused=NOT PAUSED Triggers #=1

Name= INSTANT_KPI_DEF_ID_1000829 Group=DEFAULT NextFireTime=Thu Feb 09 15:15:30 CET 2017 Priority=5 Paused=NOT PAUSED Triggers #=1

Name= INSTANT_KPI_DEF_ID_1000707 Group=DEFAULT NextFireTime=Thu Feb 09 15:15:30 CET 2017 Priority=5 Paused=NOT PAUSED Triggers #=1

Name= INSTANT_KPI_DEF_ID_1000828 Group=DEFAULT NextFireTime=Thu Feb 09 15:15:30 CET 2017 Priority=5 Paused=NOT PAUSED Triggers #=1

Name= INSTANT_KPI_DEF_ID_1000706 Group=DEFAULT NextFireTime=Thu Feb 09 15:15:30 CET 2017 Priority=5 Paused=NOT PAUSED Triggers #=1

Name= INSTANT_KPI_DEF_ID_1000827 Group=DEFAULT NextFireTime=Thu Feb 09 15:15:30 CET 2017 Priority=5 Paused=NOT PAUSED Triggers #=1

Name= INSTANT_KPI_DEF_ID_1000705 Group=DEFAULT NextFireTime=Thu Feb 09 15:15:30 CET 2017 Priority=5 Paused=NOT PAUSED Triggers #=1

Name= INSTANT_KPI_DEF_ID_1000826 Group=DEFAULT NextFireTime=Thu Feb 09 15:15:30 CET 2017 Priority=5 Paused=NOT PAUSED Triggers #=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that quartz is by default configured to have only 10 running jobs.
I changed that to 200, now the next wall I've hit is that oracle doesn't like that many connections being made simultaneously.

```
SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
quartzScheduler.setSchedulerName("rm-quartz-scheduler");

Properties props = new Properties();

// Thread pooling
props.put("org.quartz.threadPool.class", org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool.class.getName());
props.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount", "200");
props.put("org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority", "5");

quartzScheduler.setQuartzProperties(props);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the number of connections to the database by specifying

> org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5

Refer here for sample config
[JDBC-JobStore Configuration](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html)

Comment: I am not using JobStore. There is a mechanism for server restarts to restore the job based on other data in the DB.